# C++ Read Binary file containing numbers of type double

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, ifstream, readfile

I have a binary file that contains numbers of a type double.
The example input file is available here: www.bobdanani.net/download/A.0.0
I would like to read the file and print the numbers in it. 
This is what I have done:

```
char* buffer;
int length;
string filename = "A.0.0";
ifs.open (filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
// get length of file:
ifs.seekg (0, ios::end);
length = ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg (0, ios::beg);
// allocate memory:
buffer = new char [length];
// read data as a block:
ifs.read (buffer,length);
ifs.close();

cout.write (buffer,length);
cout << buffer << endl;

delete[] buffer;
```

I have also tried to use a type casting to double when printing the number, but I got strange characters. What is the best way to do this? I need the data of this binary file as an input to a function for a parallel program. But this is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: perhaps you need to initialize the buffer before you use it, just like this: memset(buffer, 0, length)

Comment: It's impossible to answer the question without knowing the format of the double in the file.  "Binary" is not a format; and a binary double can have many different formats.

Comment: Also, it's unlikely that a _binary_ file would separate values by _text_ characters such as space/tab. Why would you even need separation?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I have corrected the question and post a link containing the example input file. Sorry I might be wrong regarding the tab separated format. It is just that when I print the values using the ( od - e filename ) shell command on bash, it print the values in tab separated format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I could be wrong, since you said the number is separated by a tab/space, I'm willing to be this is actually ASCII data, and not raw binary data.  Therefore the best way to work with the floating point value would be to use the `operator>>` on the `ifstream` object and then push that into a `double`.  That will do an automatic conversion of the input value into a double, where-as what you've done will merely copy the character bytes that compose a floating point value, but are not a floating point value themselves.  Additionaly, if you were trying to output your buffer like a string, you haven't explicitly null-terminated it, so it's going to keep reading up the stack until it encounters a null-terminator or you get a segmentation fault due to accessing memory the OS isn't allowing you to access off the top of the stack.  But either way, in the end, your buffer won't be a representation of a `double` data-type.

So you would have something like:

```
double my_double_val;

ifs.open (filename.c_str());

if (ifs)
{
    ifs >> my_double_val;
}
else
{
    cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
}

ifs.close();

cout << "Double floating point value: " << my_double_val << endl;
```

Comment: He said he's willing to bet that it's text data

Comment: True, and since the OP mentioned that his numbers are separated by a tab/space, this does not sound like "binary" data, but more like ASCII data, which I guess could be mis-interpreted as binary data since ASCII is just a series of bytes as well.  I've just never heard of a binary format that required tab/space separators ...

Comment: @Jason: There's a reason for that: There's a significant chance (about 6%, per stored double) that the IEEE binary encoding of a double would include either (0x20) space or (0x09) tab as one of the 8 bytes.  Having a character with an ambiguous meaning does not make a useful file format.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I have corrected the question and post a link containing the example input file. Sorry I might be wrong regarding the tab separated format. It is just that when I print the values using the ( od - e filename ) shell command on bash, it print the values in tab separated format.

Comment: Well, the easiest thing to-do then, if that command gives you the numbers you want, is using the command-line, pipe the output of `od` into your program and then read from `stdin`.  So for instance, you could do `od -e filename | my_c_plusplus_prog`, and in your program, just use the `operator>>` with `std::cin` and do something like `cin >> int_index >> double1 >> double2;`, where `index` is an integer, and `double1` and `double2` are floating point values.  At least when I run `od` on your file, that is the format it seems to be outputting.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout.write (buffer,length);
```

Don't do this! The above is going to dump the binary data to standard output.

```
cout << buffer << endl;
```

Don't do this either! The above will dump the binary data up to the first byte that happens to be zero to standard output. If there is no such byte, this will just keep on going past the end of the buffer (so undefined behavior).

**If** the buffer truly does contain doubles, and only doubles, you can do something nasty like

```
double * dbuf = reinterpret_cast<double*>(buffer);
int dlength = length / sizeof(double);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the system function call in C++ (assuming you are using unix OS) and pass `'od -e filename'` as the argument of the system function call. And then you can easily pipe the values that it returned and read  them. This is one approach. Of course there are many other approaches to do this.